# font error - python tkinter label

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts, label

im using the anurati (google it if you dont know what it is) font on win 10 i tried calling it from tkinter to recive the error

my code is :

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("P.E.T.A.R")
txt = Label(root, text = "welcome to project petar")
txt.grid(column = 0, row = 0, font=("Anurati Regular"))
```

and the error is

```
================ RESTART: C:\Users\dell\Desktop\p.e.t.a.r.py ================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\p.e.t.a.r.py", line 6, in <module>
    txt.grid(column = 0, row = 0, font=("Anurati Regular", 50))
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2082, in grid_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-font": must be -column, -columnspan, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, -row, -rowspan, or -sticky
>>>
```

why does this happen

Comment: would it be better to just use a picture of the text?

Comment: why using the font inside the `grid` method ?

Comment: @elitegamer88 No it would not be better to use an image. That will get old quick when adding new content or updating. You just need to fix some minor mistakes to get this working. See my answer for an explanation of the problem.

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory: `font` is not a valid option for the `grid` command.

Comment: It's not that straitforward

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to render font before and you are also using it incorrectly.

Use this code at the start:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font
my_font = tkinter.font.Font(root,family="Anurati Regular")
```

Then you can use it like:

```
txt = Label(root, text = "welcome to project petar",font=my_font)
txt.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
```

Thus, your overall code will be like:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font
root = Tk()
root.title("P.E.T.A.R")
my_font = tkinter.font.Font(root,family="Anurati Regular")
txt = Label(root, text = "welcome to project petar",font=my_font)
txt.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
```

### Edit:

As you said in your comment that `this method does not create the font just a different version of the default` , you are calling your font with incorrect name or the font isn't installed and when this happens, `tkinter` creates a basic font. To prove that this method works , I have made another code which uses Windows builtin fonts:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font
root = Tk()
root.title("P.E.T.A.R")
my_font = tkinter.font.Font(root,family="Comic Sans MS")
my_font2 = tkinter.font.Font(root,family="Copperplate Gothic Bold")
txt = Label(root, text = "welcome to project petar",font=my_font)
txt.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
txt2 = Label(root, text = "welcome to project petar",font=my_font2)
txt2.grid(column = 0, row = 1)
```

On executing this code :

[image: Workig]

### Edit 2:

I have made further investigation , downloaded `Anurati` font and finally realized that I was correct. It has two problems:

- You calling incorrect name. The name is `Anurati` but you are using `Anurati Regular`. You should use `my_font = tkinter.font.Font(root,family="Anurati")`
- The small letters of this font are simple while capital are not. And have written the text is small letters. Your text should be `txt = Label(root, text = "WELCOME TO PROJECT PETAR",font=my_font)`

After that your final code becomes:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font
root = Tk()
root.title("P.E.T.A.R")
my_font = tkinter.font.Font(root,family="Anurati")
txt = Label(root, text = "WELCOME TO PROJECT PETAR",font=my_font)
txt.grid(row=0,column=0)
```

So after running the code above, you will get the expected ouput:
[image: Anurati]

Comment: `You have to render font ,not use it as option.`... This is incorrect. You can use it as an option they just put it in the wrong location.

Comment: this may be an issue with my font but this method does not create the font just a different version of the default

Comment: @elitegamer88 Its becuase you have entered incorrect font name. Usually , when tkinter don't a font available, then it creates a custom font.

Comment: Check [this site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Microsoft_Windows) to see that which fonts are included in windows.

Comment: No the font dissent work because the font only supports upper case letters (caps)

Comment: @elitegamer88 check this image https://imgur.com/a/495UPty . Now whatever, you have rendered the font correctly , its now up to you that how will you use it. You can ask me for help if needed.

Comment: It's the correct name as I checked my pcs font folder

Comment: @Nouman thanks for that link I was trying to find a list like this.